# Sort Data Column to Retrieve Max textual value

Tags: mysql, search, select

I have a column of data called the order number (orderNum) that can be anything like the following:

`1124, 203, 5467, MANUAL1, MANUAL34, DEMO12, DEMO998, INTERNAL2312, INTERNAL232`

and essentially, I need to write a SQL query to retrieve the "largest" order number of a certain type. The actual orders that are integers is trivial, but the sorting that MySQL does with `VARCHAR`s is a little wacky. So out of the dataset above, if I was looking for the next manual order number, I would need to be able to tell that `MANUAL34` was the last used  manual order number, `INTERNAL2312`, `DEMO12` (the numbers will go up sequentially by 1). Is there a way to achieve this without having to pull out the entire column and sort it in my Java web service?

Comment: The real problem here is that the `orderNum` field is combining two attributes of the `order` entity: type and number.  It would be best to change the database schema to separate those attributes into their own columns.

Comment: @Xint0 absolutely true, but this system is already in production unfortunately. Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
select * from testing where value like 'MANUAL%' 
order by CAST(right(value, length(value)-length('MANUAL')) as UNSIGNED) desc 
LIMIT 1
```

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5831d/5)

Comment: woooo, that is excellent. I am going to have to look into those functions you used (`cast`, `right`) as I have never seen them used before. Thank you!